Firebase authentication with SvelteKit is not working
I was trying to implement Firebase authentication with Svelte Kit and did everything accordingly to this repository https://github.com/eraygundogmus/sveltekit-firebase-auth-example
Although it's not working - when the login modal window is opened nothing is there, but a message saying that host 127.0.0.1 refusing connection on port 9099.
How it's set up in firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}

And firebase.client.ts
export let db: Firestore;
export let app: FirebaseApp;
export let auth: Auth;

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    appId: import.meta.env. VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    useEmulator: 'true',
    authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
};

export const initializeFirebase = () => {
    if (!browser) {
        throw new Error("Can't use the Firebase client on the server.");
    }
    if (!app) {
        app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        auth = getAuth(app);

        if (firebaseConfig.useEmulator) {
            connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099');
        }
    }
};


What is wrong here?

Closing the question - was resolving  via the declining emulator - connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099');
